# Creating SQL table, foreign_key confusion

Tags: sql, reference, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-table

[image: schema]

One question, I have supervisor set as foreign key.
He collect information through Activity Participant and take it from person ID.

Question:

How should I create the `Activity` table? what do I have to write down about supervisor?

```
CREATE TABLE activity
(
act_id VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT activity_pk PRIMARY KEY,
act_type VARCHAR2(20),
act_desc VARCHAR2(30),
act_date DATE,
mor_aft VARCHAR2(9),
CONSTRAINT activity_sup_fk FOREIGN KEY (act_supVisor) REFERENCES person()
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign key must reference a unique key of the referenced table.  Either the table's primary key, or else a secondary unique key.

```
CONSTRAINT activity_sup_fk FOREIGN KEY (act_supVisor) 
  REFERENCES person(Person_id)
```

Comment: It just like this? Hah...... will try, I just start to confuse my self and imagine that this will much harder))